# Get Default Area Paths and Iteration Paths Programatically

Tags: tfs

I want to get work item's default Area Path and Iteration Path Programatically in TFS. How to get them?. My code is C#

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem by doing independent research and consulting the API documentation?

Comment: Now I am studying in TFS API Document, but I can not find how to do.

Comment: What do you mean by a work items default area? Do you mean the teams defaults? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default area and iteration for a work item created outside of the context of a team is the same as the project name.

If you set an area and iteration path of "/[teamProjectName]" you will be able to save the work item in the API.